# Get image URLs from the text that only contains specific word inside URL string

Tags: php, parsing, url, preg-match, match

I use preg_match_all to get all images URLs from the text string:

```
preg_match_all('!http://[^?#]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $text , $matches);
```

- Unfortunately, this time I need to get only images that contains '/bigimage/' inside the initial string.
- i.e.
  $matches array should have only contains image elements like:

> ```
>   http://x/x/bigimage/x/x.jpg
> ```

- How could I modify source command to get desired result?

Comment: You can add the directory name to the pattern... `http://[^?#]+(/bigimage/)+.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)`, there may be better solutions with people who are familiar with REG-Ex a bit more.

Comment: Tell.. what do you want to capture exactly ? **filename ? filename with extension?whole path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
(http://(?:\w+/)*bigimage(?:/\w+)*((/\w).(?:jpe?g|png|gif)))
```

for visualization 
https://www.debuggex.com/r/22db9byd3cTlIX6f

**Change the *brackets () or capturing groups* according to your need**